# Replace values in multiple appsettings files stored in different artifacts during VSTS Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to replace `appsettings.json` and  `e2e-appsettings.json` variables stored in  two different artifacts  in the release pipeline.

As per below code, ONLY `appsettings.json` is updating, but for the second line it gives an error,

error: `NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: e2e/XXX.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/e2e-appsettings.json`

[image]

As per the information it should be the relative path to root. So in this case not sure what should be the root as there are two build artifacts.

Further in download artifact logs says,

```
2019-04-09T02:33:55.9132583Z Downloaded e2e/XXX.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/e2e-appsettings.json to D:\a\r1\a\EstimationCore\e2e\XXX.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\e2e-appsettings.json
```

The artifact with other appsettings.json file which is working fine is a zip file. logs, `Downloading app/app.zip to D:\a\r1\a\EstimationCore\app\app.zip`

These I have already tried which gave the same error

```
- NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: e2e/XXX.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/e2e-appsettings.json.
- NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: **/*e2e-appsettings.json
- NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: d:\a\r1\a\EstimationCore\e2e\XXX.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\e2e-appsettings.json.
- NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: d:\a\r1\a\EstimationCore\**\**\e2e-appsettings.json.
```

Comment: Try to add "EstimationCore" before the "e2e/XXX....."

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Unfortunately same results. I added few other combinations to the question which I already tried out.